# Mapped drive not deployed by GPO Azure AD

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, gpo

I've a GPO that won't work in Azure AD. I need to create multiple GPOs to map network drives. I've put the GPO right under the domain

[image: Group Policy Management]

I've mapped the drive, and targeted at a security group. Tried with an OU first, but that didn't work either.
[image: Drive mapping]
[image: Item targeting]

So did I place the GPO wrong, or did I map the drive wrong? The client has a dynamic IP and it's DNS servers are the IP of the servers
[image: IP]

When I run `gpudate` on the client, It seems that the server is unreachable:
[image: gpupdate]

Let me know if you need additional information

Comment: Sorry about the late answer. We managed to solve it. It seemed that GPO is not supported in Azure that way we did it in our project

Comment: We didn't try that, because it was past our deadline. And I didn't see your comment before then.

Answer (score 0):

•   Your procedure of mapping a network drive is correct but the error snapshot that you have posted regarding the reachability of the AD/DNS servers is a matter of concern due to which the group policies were not able to replicate and apply authoritatively from the AD or Group policy server. Thus, please check the connectivity of the DC/Group policy server from the client system as below: -

A)  Check the SYSVOL replication is happening correctly or not. DFRS (Distributed File Replication Service) is used for SYSVOL replication, to confirm that run the below command and check its result

```
        ‘ dfsrmig.exe /getglobalstate ’ --> If the result shows: 3 (ELIMINATED), then its Ok
```

B)  Then check whether which DC has the FSMO roles installed on it. For that, run the below command and check the IP and hostname whether it is configured as the correct DNS in IP configuration in the client system or not

```
     ‘ netdom query fsmo ’
```

C)  Once the above is done, please check the replication between the DCs is working correctly or not by executing the below commands one by one and analyzing their results

```
      ‘ Dcdiag /v >c:\dcdiag1.log
        Repadmin /showrepl
        Repadmin /syncall /APeD ‘
```

D)  Ensure that the ‘gpt.ini’ file exists on your DC at ‘\domain.local\SysVol\domain.local\Policies{Policy_GUID}\’ path and if not then your GPO server might be at risk of corruption of essential system files. Please reset it. Also, do ensure that your DNS server or DC is reachable and pingable through the below commands successfully. Try to reset the DNS resolver cache on client computers.

```
     ‘ ping<hostname of DC>
       Nslookup<hostname of DC>
       Ipconfig /flushdns ’  on client systems
```

Lastly, ensure that your DC and domain is accessible via RPC protocol through the below command: -

```
 ‘ nltest /dsgetdc:hostname of DC ’
```

If all of the above commands return positive results, then you should check your client’s network and domain settings for any issues as everything else is correct on the DC end.